# cmake find_package: only minimum version in version range

Tags: cmake

Say I only require a minimum version of a package but no maximum version, can I do this with `find_package` (from cmake 3.19 on)?. So I do not want

```
find_package(LLVM ...<12 REQUIRED)
```

but something like

```
find_package(LLVM 11... REQUIRED)
```

,i.e., not specifying a maximum version of the package.

Comment: I think `LLVM 11...9999` will be safe for a loooooooooooooooooong time.

Comment: Yes, but it does not look nice in a CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I think you can just use:

```
find_package(LLVM 11 REQUIRED)
```

CMake will treat that number as a minimum version required.

### Aside

I ran into a similar problem for Python and found that just specifying a single version worked like specifying a minimum. For example,

```
find_package(Python 3.11 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)
```

Yielded:

```
-- Found Python: /path_to_python/python3 (found suitable version "3.11.3", minimum required is "3.11") found components: Interpreter
```